# Passing an Object as Navigator Pop response

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to pass an object as `Navigator.pop` response but I get this error :

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, Animal>' in type cast
```

Here was my approach :

```dart
     Navigator.pop(context, {
            'animal': state.animal as Animal,
            'hospital': state.hospital as Hospital
          });
```

On route push :

```
    Animal? animal;
    Hospital? hospital;

    Navigator.of(context)
              .push<void>(DetailInfo.route(context))
              .then((value) {
            animal =
                (value as Map<String, Animal>)['animal'];
            hospital = (value as Map<String, Hospital>)['hospital'];
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `Animal` and `Hospital` are different types but they are all `Object`.

The solution is:

```dart
final data = value as Map<String, Object>;
animal = data['animal'] as Animal?;
hospital = data['hospital'] as Hospital?;
```